# Cannot decide about condition in while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

I am making a program about inputting 'n' number of integers from the user and calculating the even and odd sums respectively. However, I am being confused about the condition I should put in while loop. Other than that the sums of even and odd numbers are being calculated perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, n, number, sum = 0, summ = 0, count;
    printf("Enter Number of Integers:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i <= n)
    {
        i = number;
        printf("Enter Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        i++;
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + number;
            number++;
        }
        else if (number % 2 != 0)
        {
            summ = summ + number;
            number++;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of Even Numbers: %d", sum);
    printf("\nSum of Odd Numbers: %d", summ);
}
```

Comment: `i=number;` is probably incorrect.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized.

Comment: While loop used in case if the iteration number is unknown usually, but in your case its `n`. Why dont you use a `for` loop instead? Also you not just initialize your `i` to an unitialized variable at first iteration, but you also overwrite it in every iteration, so it does not work properly as an iteration counter.

Comment: drop i=number; your sums would be wrong if you give first number greater than number of integers

Comment: It worked. Thankyou all.

Comment: The `number++;` lines are fairly weird — they should go.  You need `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, the idiomatic C loop for counting over `0` .. `n - `.  Then lose the `i = number;` line and the now extraneous `i++;` line.You should test the result of `scanf()` to ensure someone didn't type `abcd` when you expected them to type `-234567` or some other number.

Comment: Your code will produce multiple warnings when you compile it. *Don't just ignore them*. Your compiler is telling you that even though it could compile your code, it's probably buggy and you should fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just decrease n on each loop.
Simplify your odd test

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,sum=0,summ=0;
    printf("Enter Number of Integers:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n-- > 0)
    {
        int number;
        printf("Enter Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if(number % 2) {
            summ += number;
        }
        else {
            sum += number;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of Even Numbers: %d\n",sum);
    printf("Sum of Odd Numbers: %d\n",summ);
}
```

Comment: ...and check the return value of `scanf`; what happens if I enter `four`?

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is better to declare the variable that holds the number of integers as having the type unsigned int.

For example

```
unsigned int n = 0;

printf( "Enter Number of Integers: " );
scanf( "%u", &n );
```

then the loop can look like

```
int success = 1;

while ( success && n-- )
{
    int number;

    printf( "Enter Number: " );
    success = scanf( "%d", &number ) == 1;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( number % 2 == 0 ) sum += number;
        else summ += number;
    }
}

printf( "Sum of Even Numbers: %d\n", sum );
printf("\nSum of Odd Numbers: %d\n", summ );
```

Pay attention to that the user can interrupt the input. You should process such a case in the program.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int sum = 0, summ = 0;
    unsigned int n = 0;

    printf( "Enter Number of Integers: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    int success = 1;

    while ( success && n-- )
    {
        int number;

        printf( "Enter Number: " );
        success = scanf( "%d", &number ) == 1;

        if ( success )
        {
            if ( number % 2 == 0 ) sum += number;
            else summ += number;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nSum of Even Numbers: %d\n", sum );
    printf( "Sum of Odd Numbers: %d\n", summ );     
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter Number of Integers: 10
Enter Number: 1
Enter Number: 2
Enter Number: 3
Enter Number: 4
Enter Number: 5
Enter Number: 6
Enter Number: 7
Enter Number: 8
Enter Number: 9
Enter Number: 10

Sum of Even Numbers: 30

Sum of Odd Numbers: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though other answers correct they might too complicated for a beginners eyes. I would strongly advise the use a `for` loop for less confusion. Also give better names for your variables to make even more clear what is going on.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, sum_even = 0, sum_odd = 0, number;

    printf("Enter Number of Integers:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (number % 2)
            sum_odd += number;
        else
            sum_even += number;

    }
    printf("Sum of Even Numbers: %d\n", sum_even);
    printf("Sum of Odd Numbers: %d\n", sum_odd);
}
```